# How to fill Jquery UI Progress bar with radio button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I would like to have a Jquery UI Progress bar fill up according to how many questions have been answered in a form.

I have roughly 46 questions with radio buttons acting as 3 options to choose from per question.

I want the progress bar to be full when all the questions have been completed.

I will post code if necessary but I think this is explanation enough...

thank you to anyone who replys..

cheers.

Comment: You need to calculate the percentage at per click.and give that percentage to div's width property..well show me your full code.how are you calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/9dEpa/. Could be more efficient and stuff. But this works and is extensible. The id of the radio buttons can be whatever you want, just make them unique. And the names just have to start with the same thing.